# How to Fix Mac Excel Weird Keyboard Entry Behavior

Tags: excel, macos, ms-office

If I want cell C1 to be the sum of A1 and B1, I do this on Windows Excel and it works as expected:

<kbd>=</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

C1 formula shows `=A1+B1`

However, doing the same thing on Mac Excel (version 16.22 190211) fails. After

<kbd>=</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>

the C1 formula shows `=A1`

Upon typing <kbd>+</kbd>, the `A1` reference gets overwritten and C1 formula becomes `=+` instead of the expected `=A1+`

This happens consistently with different operator/operands sequence that I am unable to enter formulas properly. How does one perform "normal" keyboard entry with Mac Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just done exactly what you suggest:

=←←+←ENTER

on a macbook pro, excel ver 16.38 and works perfectly

On an Imac, excel v 15.16 with a wired keyboard works perfectly
and same Imac with a wireless keyboard works perfectly.

Either a keyboard error or Operator error.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I upgraded my Excel to 16.26 and it is working perfectly now. Looks like the 16.22 version is buggy.